# API.AI - Catch Strings between quotation marks?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I use api.ai to understand what end-user wants from my app.
One of my apps functionalities is translating text using google api.
For that i need to catch string between quotation marks.

How to catch them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the @sys.any for that. It's a system entity that can be used to capture any kind of string conform a sentence structure.

I've post a picture below as an example of how I achieved this with the expected output.

[API.ai Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bfKf.png)